# extracting json in php

Tags: php, json

From MySQL row, I have this json formatted data:

```
$row['details'] =
{
"previous_employer":[
    {"employer":"string1","address":"address1"},
    {"employer":"string2","address":"address2"},
    {"employer":"string3","address":"address3"}],

"profile":[
    "firstname":"John",   
    "lastname":"Adams", 
    "gender":"male",
    "age":"35",
    "contact":"123456789"]
}
```

I want to extract employer and address on the previous_employer array of objects, 
    but when I do this:

```
$json = json_decode($row['details'],true); //decode into array

foreach($json['previous_employer'] as $d){
    echo "employer:".$d['employer']."<br>address:". $d['address']."<br>";
}
```

it gives me an error of

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can I fix this? Pls advise.. thanks!

Comment: `var_dump($json);` `var_dump($json['previous_employer']);`

Comment: var_dump($json); // outputs NULL

Comment: var_dump($json['previous_employer']); //outputs NULL

Comment: That is not valid json, your `profile` key does not contain an array, it should be an object or perhaps an array of objects like the `previous_employer` key.

Answer (score 1):

You JSON is invalid, `"profile"` must be

An Object:

```
"profile": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Adams",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": "35",
        "contact": "123456789"
    }
```

or an Array of Object (here his length == 1)

```
"profile": [{
        "John",
        "Adams",
        "male",
        "35",
        "123456789"
    }]
```

or a Simple Array (not associative array/map)

```
"profile": [
        "John",
        "Adams",
        "male",
        "35",
        "123456789"
    ]
```

Now, your posted code will work as a charm without any modifications ... :)

Comment: Of course, invalid JSON can be diagnosed, there's no need to code blindly ;)

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) does not necessarily succeed (just imagine you feed it with complete garbage, why should it return *something*?). You need to do the following error checking:

1. Verify its return value:

   > Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
   >   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
   >   respectively. **NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the
   >   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit**.
2. If valid data can be expected to return `null` some times, call [json_last_error()](http://php.net/json_last_error) and check whether it's `JSON_ERROR_NONE`.

Last but not least, you can explore any variable with [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump). You don't need to make assumptions about its content.